# Magento2 Unit Test - Mock setExtensionAttributes()

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests

I cannot mock `ProductOptionInterface::setExtensionAttributes`, I get this error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException : Cannot mock Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductOptionInterface::setExtensionAttributes() because a class or interface used in the signature is not loaded
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method is

```
public function setExtensionAttributes(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductOptionExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
);
```

And the error message tells you that a class or interface of the signature is not loaded. This means that the interface `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductOptionExtensionInterface` cannot be found.

The "Extension" interfaces are generated files with getters and setters, this particular one should be in `var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductOptionExtensionInterface.php`

To make autoloading and code generation work with unit tests you need to use the test bootstrap file from Magento:

```
phpunit --bootstrap dev/tests/unit/framework/bootstrap.php YOUR_TEST
```

If you are running the unit tests from within the `dev/tests/unit` directory itself, this should already work because the bootstrap file is defined in `phpunit.xml.dist` there.

Comment: It real works. Thank you. The problem was that i use default "phpunit.xml.dist". When i show the path to dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist it resolve my problem